# Find cars when nearest to each other

Tags: calculus

At noon a car drives from $A$ toward $C$ at $60$ miles per hour. Another car, starting $B$ at the same time, drives toward $A$ at $30$ miles per hour. If $AB = 42$ miles., find when cars will be nearest each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten to mention that AC is perpendicular to BC (that's a standard problem). Otherwise also you would be given some information about how their paths are. Use it to calculate the distance between them as function of x and then minimise it (take out the 1st derivative and equate it to 0 and for that x check whether it's a Minima by finding the 2nd derivative ).